# Convert List of one type to Array of another type using Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to convert List of string to Array of userdefinedType and for array I need to convert string to long.

I have achieved the same using  below approach to achieve it

```
TeamsNumberIdentifier[] securityPolicyIdArray = securityPolicyIds.stream()
                .map(securityPolicy -> new TeamsNumberIdentifier(Long.valueOf(securityPolicy)))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new))
                .toArray(new TeamsNumberIdentifier[securityPolicyIds.size()]);
```

Is there any better approach to convert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
securityPolicyIds.stream()
                 .map(Long::valueOf)
                 .map(TeamsNumberIdentifier::new)
                 .toArray(TeamsNumberIdentifier[]::new);
```

Comment: This is more efficient one and more clean , I will use the same

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to create a temporary ArrayList. Just use toArray() on the stream:

```
TeamsNumberIdentifier[] securityPolicyIdArray = securityPolicyIds.stream()
            .map(securityPolicy -> new TeamsNumberIdentifier(Long.valueOf(securityPolicy)))
            .toArray(TeamsNumberIdentifier[]::new);
```

But in general, I would tend to avoid arrays in the first place, and use lists instead.

Comment: I too does the same but my API needs arrays instead of lists